# Breakpoints hit but not displayed in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin Studio 5.10.2. In the debugger I can set breakpoints, run, and the debugger does stop at the breakpoints.  However, it does *not* bring the location of the breakpoint into view.  I know the breakpoint is hit because it displays the call stack in its window.  When I double-click on the top item of the call stack, the source file is opened and the line pending execution is displayed in the center of the editor.

I can step along execution and see the lines highlight as it goes through them, but it never re-centers the current line and it will step right off the bottom of the window. (I can keep it in view by either manually scrolling or double-clicking the top line of the call stack.)

In Visual Studio (with which I'm much more familiar), the pending execution line is displayed automatically when the breakpoint is hit---no need to double-click on the call stack.  Is there a way to get this behavior in Xamarin Studio?

Comment: This should just work as you expect... You should open bug report at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com